# My Nikon Digital D50 is showing black screen when I take photos

Tags: nikon, troubleshooting, repair

[image][image]I am camera illiterate and I am trying to surprise my husband by fixing his Nikon digital camera that all of a sudden stopped working after I let my brother use it.

HELP!

It turns on, and takes photo, even with a flash but then the screen does not show the photo. I know the screen isnt broken because the settings show up and the "black screen" still shows 3/3 and some other information.

Comment: What do the photos look like when you transfer them to a computer?  What is the other information about the photo that you see displayed on the screen?  What are the exposure settings of the photos?  (ISO, shutter speed, aperture)

Comment: If you press playback to show your photo, is it showing up then? In that case you might have switched automatic review of the photo off in the menu.

Comment: thank you so much for your response! I just added two photos of what the screens look like... playback is still black and slideshow is all black images... hopefully this helps. Thank you again!!

Comment: As you have a slideshow of black images, it is not the review function.

Answer (score 2):

There is insufficient information to know what is wrong with it or if it can be fixed without sending it to a service center. If there is a defective component then, you will have to go that route but there are several things to try before:

- First, since you said the settings show, perform a camera reset. There is a *Settings* menu where you will find the *Reset* option to reset the camera configuration of menu items to their default.
- Second, the exposure may simply be off which will not be fixed by the reset since dials are involved. To check this, move the *Mode Dial* to the *Auto* or *P* position.

Try to take a photo after doing the above. Listen to the camera carefully. You should hear 4 sounds: a loud one when the mirror goes up, two quiet ones when the shutter opens and closes, followed by a loud one when the mirror goes down. While the mirror goes up and down, the viewfinder will temporarily black out. If that does not happen, then you need to have it serviced to fix the mirror mechanism. If you hear the loud sound but not a low one, then it's the shutter that is broken which also requires servicing.

Unfortunately, if you hear both sounds after having reset the camera then you probably have a more expensive problem to repair such as a dead sensor. Those are too expensive to practically fix for an old entry-level camera and it will cost significantly less to buy another working camera in the used market. The good news is that you can expect a much better used camera for the price of fixing a sensor.

Comment: Wow thank you so much for all of this information and taking the time to help me- it means a lot! I provided two more photos of the screens. Hopefully there is something glaring on there that helps fix this. I looked through my settings and only found a "reset menu" nothing that was clear to reset the camera....

Comment: *Reset Menu* is what resets the camera except for the dials which can't be reset via any setting but once you are on auto and the menu is reset you should be in a good state to ensure it's not settings.

Comment: @ColetteSimpson - That is black photo for what would be reasonable settings, assuming the lens cap is off, so did you listen for sounds? Maybe the mirror or shutter is broken which are serviceable parts.

Comment: Thank you so much- I did a reset and it still is showing a black screen when the photo is taken. I also listened for the sounds and all seem to working- the viewfinder temp blacked out and all the sounds seem to be on point with how they should be working. Sounds like I may have a really expensive problem. Darn, thought this was going to be easy and I was just not savvy with the camera!

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on what you have described is that the sensor is bad. Black image on the lcd, even on playback and when viewed on the computer.  No, your brother didn't break it.  It happens.  Look for another used camera. A repair would be too expensive.

I'm assuming you didn't leave the lens cap on.  That happens too.